# Regular expression with backreferences

Tags: c#, regex, backreference

I am attempting to write a regular expression in a C# application to find "{value}", along with a backreference to the text before it up to "[[", and another backreference to the text after it up to "]]". For example:

```
This is some text [[backreference one {value} 
backreference two]]
```

Would match "[[backreference one ", "{value}", and "\r\nbackreference two]]".

I have tried modified versions of the following with no luck. I believe I am missing word boundaries, and may be having trouble because of "{" in the text I am trying to find.

```
\[\[(^[\{value\}]+)\{value\}(^\]\]+)\]\]
```

I'm not sure if it would be possible with regular expressions, but it would be ideal if it could find the matching closing bracket, for example the following would find "[[backreferenc[[e]] one ", "{value}", and "ba[[ckref[[e]]rence t]]wo]]":

```
This is some text [[backreferenc[[e]] one {value} 
ba[[ckref[[e]]rence t]]wo]]
```

Comment: Could you put some real examples?

Comment: Basically I am trying to allow a syntax that will remove a label if the value doesn't exist. So if I am replacing {name} and {address} in the following and {address} is empty, to not show "Address: ". [[Name: {name}\r\n]][[Address: {address}]]. So currently I am replacing {address} with an empty string, but would like to modify that so it replaces {address}, along with the text before up to [[ and the text after until ]].

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [MatchEvaluator on Regex replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx). Also it would make your life easier by breaking up the matches into named capture groups to help with the match evaluator processing. Let me explain.

What the MatchEvaluator does, is it allows one to intercede in the match process with a C# delegate and return what should be replaced when a match happens by examining the actual match captured. That way you can do your text processing as needed.

Here is a basic example where it handles the sections in a basic way, but the structure is there to add your business logic:

```
string text = @"This is some text [[Name: {name}]] at [[Address: {address}]].";

Regex.Replace(text,
              @"(?:\[\[)(?<Section>[^\:]+)(?:\:)(?<Data>[^\]]+)(?:\]\])",
              new MatchEvaluator((mtch) =>
              {
                    if (mtch.Groups["Section"].Value == "Name")
                            return "Jabberwocky";

                  return "120 Main";

              }));
```

The result of Regex Replace is:

```
This is some text Jabberwocky at 120 Main.
```

Answer (score 1):

To the first part of you question try this:

```
\[\[(.*)({value})(.*)\]\]
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I am trying to match "not {value}" up until "{value}", so the above would fail in the following example: [[ some{text {value}]]